# mysql_num_rows in laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, mysql-num-rows, laravel-query-builder

im trying to use mysql_num_rows in laravel but laravel says it not the same way like in 'raw php'

> example:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
         ->where('username', '=', $username)
         ->where('password', '=', $password)
         ->get();
```

> what i want to do:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($users);

   if($count > 0 ){

      $user->login = $request->login;
      $user->email = $request->email;
      $user->password = $request->password;

      Auth::login($user);
      return redirect("/");
      }else{
         return "datos incorrectos";
      }
```

> what laravel says:

```
Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\mysql_num_rows()
```

PD: its not philosophy of code just make commets about that question, i dont want answers like "u gonna crypt that thing?", "why not use [insert my faborite ORM]" is just a simple question THANKS

Comment: If this is the same project that you were working on a few days ago, you should add that, because you're interfacing with a legacy project with its own password hashing scheme, you can't simply use Laravel's built-in cryptography to hash passwords and handle authentication.

Comment: is true Auth::login($user); dont works yet but i feel close to resolve how to do that legacy thing and learn how things works in the proccess and later learn how to upgrade that but step by step

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using mysql_* functions, you should use `count()` instead. It can be chained to [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#retrieving-aggregates), [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#aggregates), or [collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count).

```
$users_count = DB::table('users')
     ->where('username', '=', $username)
     ->where('password', '=', $password)
     ->count();
```

Comment: u mean like that: $users = DB::table('users')
         ->where('username', '=', $username)
         ->where('password', '=', $password)
         ->get()->count();    ERROR:Call to a member function count() on array

Comment: Note, @DevilSystem, that in cmnardi's answer, he's not chaining `get()`.

Comment: Pay attetion to your Laravel version too.. I think it don't change, but I'm not sure

Comment: @cmnardi Fortunately, `count()` has been around since at least [Laravel 4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#aggregates)

Comment: `->count()` only works on collections, you have not returned a collection but an instance of the query builder. Updated your answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I rolled your edit back; the query builder does accept `count()` and other aggregate methods ([Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#aggregates))

Comment: @ChrisForrence Good call!